# Why am I now getting a conda environment error every time I open new terminal?

Tags: terminal, anaconda, conda

I have been working on creating custom environments using conda for new projects on my local machine (mac os). Within a project directory I created a new environment using yml file with:

```
$ conda env create --prefix ./env --file environment.yml
```

then:

```
$ conda activate ./env
```

I am now getting a conda error report every time I open a terminal and I do not understand what is going on. If anyone has any insight on what I broke and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. I hope I have included enough information here to understand the problem. Here is the error output from terminal:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 140, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 1210, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
      File "/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 178, in execute
        return getattr(self, self.command)()
      File "/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 152, in activate
        builder_result = self.build_activate(self.env_name_or_prefix)
      File "/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 300, in build_activate
        return self._build_activate_stack(env_name_or_prefix, False)
      File "/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 326, in _build_activate_stack
        conda_prompt_modifier = self._prompt_modifier(prefix, conda_default_env)
      File "/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/activate.py", line 691, in _prompt_modifier
        return context.env_prompt.format(
    KeyError: 'ds-basic'

`$ /Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate base`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                     PATH=/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/us
                          r/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /Users/jrudd/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/jrudd/.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.8.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/jrudd/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/jrudd/opt/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/jrudd/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.3 Darwin/20.3.0 OSX/10.16
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : /Users/jrudd/.netrc
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does `ds-basic` mean anything to you? That is not something from Conda. Error appears related to manipulating the PS1 (prompt modification). Is your `.zshrc` default?

Comment: Also, I've never seen one use `./env` syntax to specify Conda prefixes (the `./` seems superfluous), but I don't immediately see why it would be any issue. Could you also add the outputs from `conda config --show env_prompt` and `echo "$CONDA_ENV_PROMPT"` to the question?

Answer (score 3):

So, I found out that I had screwed up the .condarc config file by changing the base env_prompt to ({ds-basic}). For context, ds-basic is the name of this project environment. Don't ask me why or how I did this because I really have no idea. Was probably something I did during coffee induced haze. I found the .condarc file and edited out the offending code. It had actually broke conda completely and I couldn't even activate the base environment. Once I fixed the .condarc file all was well.

Answer (score 0):

The `.condarc` solution worked for me. Open it as a text file using Notepad (for Windows) and edit the file to original format, i.e. remove:

```
env_prompt : "'({<provided_name_by_user>})'"
```

You will find `.condarc` file in `C:\Users\<your_profile_name>\.condarc` (For Windows). Basically in the folder specifying system users on the drive where OS is installed.